# Summarize mysql data using GROUP BY or any other method

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
 user_id       DATE                 start_time       end_time
 1234          11/16/2013           8.30             9.30
 1234          11/16/2013           9.30             10.30
 1234          11/16/2013           12.30            13.30
 1234          11/19/2013           8.30             9.30
```

I want to  summarize data as follows, grouping time periods which follow each other:

```
 user_id       DATE                 start_time       end_time
 1234          11/16/2013           8.30             10.30
 1234          11/16/2013           12.30            13.30
 1234          11/19/2013           8.30             9.30
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: So which records to remove for this `summary`?

Comment: I think that the OP's original formatting indicated that user_id "1234" and " 1234" are different. Is that correct?

Comment: user_id "1234" and " 1234" are not  different

Comment: why dont you jus summarize `1234->11/16/2013-->8:30 -13:30 ??`

Comment: i design some booking system  that interval time  11/16/2013-->10:30 -12:30  time can book another person like  user_id 5678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution

```
SELECT user_id, date, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(end_time) end_time
  FROM
(
  SELECT user_id, date, start_time, end_time,
         @n := IF(@u = user_id AND @d = date AND CAST(@e AS TIME) = start_time, @n, @n + 1) rnum,
         @u := user_id, @d := date, @e := end_time
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @u := NULL, @d := NULL, @e := NULL) i
   ORDER BY user_id, date, start_time, end_time
) q
 GROUP BY user_id, date, rnum
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| user_id | date       | start_time | end_time |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
|    1234 | 2013-11-16 | 08:30:00   | 10:30:00 |
|    1234 | 2013-11-16 | 12:30:00   | 13:30:00 |
|    1234 | 2013-11-19 | 08:30:00   | 09:30:00 |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d71e4/12)** demo